# javascript clarification for handling null values

Tags: javascript, if-statement, null

Ok i have little section of javascript syntax and i am very confuse how null behaves. There is a lot of discussion about null values but i cant seem to figure out the problem! Please help me. Here is the script.

```
var jsonData = '<?php echo $jsonData;?>';


    if (jsonData)
    {           
        console.log('jsonData is '+ jsonData);// null or not this section is always executed! why?
    }else{
        ini(jsonData);
    }
```

I tried using '===', '!' operators but still not working as expected

Comment: `<?php ?>` tags are wrapped in `quote`..returned value will always be string like `'null'` which is `truthy` value..

Comment: I see so its a string lol. Well console.log didn't show any quotation though.

Comment: Console will never show quotes..`console.log('hi'); => hi` not `"hi"`..

Comment: i see thank your for that one. ill be sure to remember it

Answer (score 1):

this line `var jsonData = '<?php echo $jsonData;?>';` will always be a string, and if the value returned from php is null, then you will end up having var jsonData = 'null';

try this code

```
if (jsonData && jsonData != 'null' )
{           
    console.log('jsonData is '+ jsonData); //now this code will be executed only if jsonData is not null
}
else
{
    ini(jsonData);
}
```

or as mentioned by [Rayon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1746830/rayon-dabre) above, replace the assignment statement with

`var jsonData = <?php echo $jsonData;?>;`

Answer (score 0):

```
Make a check for "Null" value as well as "NAN" in your condition.
```